# Why in this inequality numerator is always negative?

Tags: inequality, real-numbers, rational-functions

Starting from:
$$\frac{x-1}{x-2}-\frac{2x-3}{x-3}>0$$
I get:
$$\frac{-x^2+3x-3}{(x-2)(x-3)}>0$$
Numerator roots are not real:
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{-3\pm \sqrt{3^2- 4 \cdot (-1) \cdot (-3)}}{-2}$$
Why can I conclude that $N(x)<0$, i.e. the numerator is always negative?
So the solution is from the denominator: $D(x)<0 \Rightarrow x \in (2,3)$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I do not understand why numerator is always negative

Comment: This is a result of the Intermediate Value Theorem: for a continuous function to go from one value to another, it has to take every value between the two. So if I ever flipped signs I'd have to go through zero, so because I don't cross through zero I can never flip signs.

Comment: In particular, a quadratic that has no real roots (i.e., never gets to “cut” the x-axis) must be floating either above or below the x-axis. Testing any point of this curve indicates that it lies below.

Answer (score 1):

You have, for each $x\in\Bbb R$,$$-x^2+3x-3=-\left(x-\frac32\right)^2-\frac34<0.$$You can also say that, since $-x^2+3x-3=-3$ when $x=0$, if you had $-x^2+3x-3>0$ for some $x\in\Bbb R$, then $-y^2+3y-3=0$ for some $y$ between $0$ and $x$, by the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: I understand that with substitution the numerator is always negative. Is there any way, other than substitution, to state that?

Comment: That's what I explain in my second paragraph: if there are no real roots and if it is negative *somewhere*, then it is negative *everywhere*.

Answer (score 0):

Every quadratic with real coefficients either has two real roots, or two non-real roots. Here, you have shown correctly that $-x^2+3x-3$ has two non-real roots, meaning that if you plot the graph $y=-x^2+3x-3$, it will not touch the $x-$axis. Furthermore, the coefficient of $x^2$ is negative, meaning that the parabola will be 'n-shaped':

[image: Graph of -x^2+3x-3]

You can also argue that if the parabola does not touch the $x$-axis, then the quadratic must be positive everywhere, or negative everywhere. If we plug in $x=0$, we find that $y=-3$, and so the quadratic must be negative everywhere.

Finally, the simplest member is probably to complete the square on $-x^2+3x-3$:
\begin{align}
-x^2+3x-3 &= -(x^2-3x+3) \\
&= -\left(\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2+3\right) \\
&= -\left(\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}\right) \\
&= -\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{3}{4}
\end{align}
The expression
$$
\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2
$$
must always be positive for real $x$.* Hence,
$$
-\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2
$$
is always negative. Therefore,
$$
-\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{3}{4}
$$
is always negative.

---

*I should really say *non-negative* for real $x$, as if $x=\frac{3}{2}$ then the expression is zero.